# Saving a DateTime in SharePoint online is not the same in all SiteCollections

Tags: sharepoint-online, timezone-offset

I noticed That on a Team Site When I save a Date Time field with My now (Central Time Zone) The look at it with REST client, the Z time is with the right offset of 5 Hours.

But on another site that I do not know how it was created, Saving the same value, shows 7 hours offset with a REST client.

From what I know, there is no Time Zone of the Site Collection. Is there a setting somewhere?

I am counting on the consistency that SPO uses the browser's current time zone to determine the UTC offset.

Anyone Knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint store datatime as UTC, so if your sites' have different time zone, the time would be different.

Save UTC time to SharePoint [as demo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01018d54-1239-4023-9195-da4c8bdffd6a/sharepoint-online-via-csom-updating-datetime-fields?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Site Settings->Regional settings

[image]

Comment: I am surprised to see that SPO is Still going by the site's Time Zone when saving as UTC. It makes no sense that User in ET saves a now date in a site that is in PT and will see it not in his own time zone.